# C - how to use strcpy for a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, strcpy

I'm trying to build a 2 dimensional array by using str.cpy, but the program fails. The code receives 4 arrays add copies their content to their matching arrays.

```
  int InsertStudent(char *firstName, char* lastName, char* dynCourses, char *dynGrades,
        char firstNames[50][20],
        char familyNames[50][20], char courses[50][5][20],
        char grades[50][5])
    {
        int set, 
        int cset = 0;
        for (set = 0; set <= (50); set++)
        {
            if (firstNames[set][cset] == '\0')
            {
                strcpy(firstNames[set][cset], firstName);
                strcpy(familyNames[set], lastName);
                for (cset = 0; cset <= 5; cset++)
                {
                    strcpy(courses[set], dynCourses);
                    strcpy(grades[set], dynGrades);
                }

            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: have you had a look at struct ? that way you can make it a little bit more object oriented

Comment: Have you learned about structures yet?  Presumably not, because your argument list cries out for a single array of a structure type: `struct Student { char firstName[20]; char familyName[20]; char courses[5][20]; char grades[5]; };` — or even `struct Course { char name[20]; char grade; }; struct Student { char firstName[20]; char familyName[20]; struct Course courses[5] };`.

Comment: the data arrays named: firstname, familyname, grades, and courses are all local, on the stack, so any operations placing data into them will all disappear when the that data goes 'out of scope' as it will when the function exits.

Answer (score 4):

- Well clearly the error is using `strcpy` wrongly.

  The correct way would be

  ```
  strcpy(firstNames[set], firstName);
  ```
- Also in the loop it should be

  ```
      for (cset = 0; cset < MAX_COURSES; cset++)
      {
          strcpy(courses[cset], dynCourses);
          strcpy(grades[cset], dynGrades);
      }
  ```

  Note that the idiomatic C loop is `for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)`, using `<` and not `<=`.

The signature of the `strcpy` function is

```
 char *strcpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

Earlier you passed in place of `s1` a char instead of `char*`. You must have got some warning (if enabled). If not then turn all compiler flags `-Wall -Werror`.

```
             if (firstNames[set][cset] == '\0')
```

But if you are initially checking an uninitilized value with `\0`. This will higly unlikely will turn out to be false. There is no gurantee that the char array which doesn't contain strings will be initialized with `0` automatically. So make sure you have initialized the char arrays in the callee function like this

```
char arr[20][50]={0};
```

- The loop is from `0` to `MAX_STUDENTS`. You are invoking an undefined behavior looping on array index out of bound if MAX_STUDENTS is greater than or equal to 50. Same goes for `MAX_COURSES`. More clearly the looping would be `for (set = 0; set < (50); set++)`.
- Again there will be a lot better way to deal with it if you put the initialization and copy part seperate. Otherwise this will be uneasy to maintain.
- Seeing your use `courses` it is obvious that you want to declare it like this

  ```
  char courses[5][20];
  ```

same goes for the `grades` array. Here you were trying to copy a string into into a 2d array. Compiler would complain about type incompatibility.

- Also in the function you didn't return anything meaningful. The correct way would be to return the index value on which new name or information is added.
- Here you are copying content of `dynGrades` and `dynCourses` to the array. So they will all contain the same values. Is this what you want? Because then what's the use of keeping 5 seperate char arrays - one could serve the purpose pretty well.

Comment: Correct. This is a function, and you're right, I will add the return value to be the student's index.

Comment: @CSstudent.: Learn to use `struct` you will make a cleaner solution.